# Conditional naming of columns in R

Tags: r

Good day,

I'm trying to figure out how to rename columns in R based on a certain set of conditions. Consider the following two examples from the code,

```
tt <- t(matrix(c(.8,.2,0)))
colnames(tt) <- c("2","3","NA")
tt

tt <- t(matrix(c(.7,.3,0)))
colnames(tt) <- c("1","3", "NA")
tt
```

Which generate the following two outputs respectively,

[image]

[image]

I want to rename the columns in such a way that "1" should be "AR(1)", "2" should be "AR(2)" "3" should be "ARMA(1,1)" and "NA" would be replaced by whichever number would be missing. So in the case of the first table that was printed "NA" would be replaced with "AR1" thus the final table should look like,

[image]

I know that the columns can be renamed using the function `colnames` as demonstrated in the example code, however I have to generate about 100+ of these types of tables, all of which will have only three names as mentioned before. So if there anyway to set this up using an ifelse statement or another method because I haven't had much luck with it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function and reuse the function on the datasets

```
f1 <- function(x)
{
nm1 <- setNames( c("AR(1)", "AR(2)", "ARMA(1,1)"), c("1", "2", "3"))
nm2 <- setdiff(names(nm1), colnames(x))
colnames(x)[colnames(x) == "NA"] <- nm2

colnames(x) <- nm1[colnames(x)]
x


}
```

-testing

```
> f1(tt)
     AR(1) ARMA(1,1) AR(2)
[1,]   0.7       0.3     0
```

Comment: This is great thank you, I came to realize that the NA column is in the form of ```<NA>``` meaning it's actual name is not "NA" but rather a column with nothing it in. However I need to have the column included with the new name.

Comment: @Warhawk1987 I couldnt use `is.na` as it is a character value.  You could change to `"<NA>"`  from `"NA"` in the code `colnames(x)[colnames(x) == "NA"] <- nm2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I tried that and unfortunately the output was the same. However after a little testing I found out that the last column will be the one that contains a 0 if if appears. Therefore I replaced the line ```colnames(x)[colnames(x) == "<NA>"] <- nm2``` with ```colnames(x)[3] <- nm2``` and that did the trick. Nevertheless, thank you for this function as it does exactly what I need. I've marked it answered so you get the proper credit.